# Is there another way to add a element inside a list and when called again the value will change?

Tags: python, list

Basically I want to add a element into i th in the string. I want to know how to fix this code.

```
    list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    def insert(list,index,element):
        list = list[:index] + [element] + list[index:]
    insert(list2,3,7)
    print(list2)
```

I expected [1,2,3,7,4,5,6,7] but got [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
P.S. I know that the list is unrelated but I want to know how to mutate the list2 without using inbuilt functions. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: you never change list 2, you only reassign a new list to the list variable in your local scope. Also try to avoid using python keywords for variable names

Comment: also list already has an insert method so why not just do `list2.insert(3, 7)`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Sorry it was a question that do not allow any inbuilt functions to be used.

Comment: myself and others have provided ways to do this without using an inbuilt function

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Sorry I was just clarifying the question you asked. I wanted to try to put everything into the function itself but I guess the only way is to put list2 =insert(list2,3,7). Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

you never make any changes to `list2` you instead allocate a new list to the localscope `list` variable. So when the function is first called `list2` and the localscope `list` are pointing to the same object in memory.

You then build a new list and point the localscope `list` at the new memory address of the new list you built. So now `list2` and `list` dont point to the same objects in memory. this is why `list2` doesnt change.

python lists already have an insert methods so you could just do this as

```
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
list2.insert(3, 7)
print(list2)
```

alternatively if you had some overwhelming reason to do this yourself in the style you wrote you would have to return the new list and assign it to `list2`

```
def insert(list, index, element):
    return list[:index] + [element] + list[index:]

list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
list2 = insert(list2, 3, 7)
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return list and update:

```
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
def insert(list,index,element):
    return list[:index] + [element] + list[index:]
list2 = insert(list2,3,7)
print(list2)
```

Better use in-built method `insert`

```
list2.insert(3, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have the assignment `list =` in your function, `list` will be considered a local variable in this function, so it is unrelated to the parameter passed to the function.

You have a few choices:

Return the new list:

```
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

def insert(lst,index,element):
    lst = lst[:index] + [element] + lst[index:]
    return lst
```

and assign the returned value:

```
list2 = insert(list2, 3, 7)  # the insert method updates the list in place
print(list2)
```

Or you have to mutate the original list, without creating a new one:

```
def insert(lst,index,element):
    lst.insert(index, element)

insert(list2, 3, 7)
print(list2)
```

But then, there isn't much use to this function, so just do

```
list2.insert(3, 7)
```

---

As a side note, avoid using `list` as a variable name, as it will shadow the original `list` builtin function.